# I'm using Tailwind in a React project. How do I successfully get the modal to fully go away after submitting? It seems that it's still greyed out

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

## **Here is my Signup.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useToken } from "./AuthenticateUser";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Signup() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [first_name, setFirst] = useState("");
  const [last_name, setLast] = useState("");
  const [zipcode, setZip] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [, , , signup] = useToken();

  const modal = document.getElementById("signup");

  const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (formValidation() === false) {
      return;
    }
    signup(first_name, last_name, email, zipcode, password);
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setFirst("");
    setLast("");
    setZip("");
    navigate("/me");
    setErrorMessage("");
    modal.classList.remove("show");
  };

  function formValidation() {
    let blankInputs = 0;
    if (email.length === 0) {
      blankInputs++;
    }
    if (password.length === 0) {
      blankInputs++;
    }
    if (first_name.length === 0) {
      blankInputs++;
    }
    if (last_name.length === 0) {
      blankInputs++;
    }
    if (zipcode.length === 0) {
      blankInputs++;
    }

    if (blankInputs === 5) {
      setErrorMessage("Form submission is completely blank.");
      return false;
    }
    if (blankInputs > 1) {
      setErrorMessage("Form has multiple blank inputs.");
      return false;
    }

    if (!validateEmail()) {
      setErrorMessage("Whoops! Email format is invalid.");
      return false;
    }
    if (zipcode.length < 5) {
      setErrorMessage("Whoops! Zipcode needs to be at least 5 characters");
      return false;
    }
    if (!password) {
      setErrorMessage("Whoops! Password is required.");
      return false;
    }
    if (!first_name) {
      setErrorMessage("Whoops! First name is required.");
      return false;
    }
    if (!last_name) {
      setErrorMessage("Whoops! Last name is required.");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  function validateEmail() {
    const regex =
      /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="modal fade fixed top-0 left-0 hidden w-full h-full outline-none overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto"
        id="signup"
        tabIndex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="signupLabel"
        aria-modal="true"
        role="dialog"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered relative w-auto pointer-events-none">
          <div className="modal-content border-none shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full pointer-events-auto bg-[#F0C797] bg-clip-padding rounded-md outline-none text-current">
            <div className="modal-header p-6 mt-2 text-center">
              <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mr-4">SIGN UP</h1>
                <img src={require("../images/checklist.png")} width="50px" />
              </div>
              <svg
                className="w-9 h-9 absolute top-3 right-2.5 text-black bg-transparent rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center hover:bg-[#FEF5ED] hover:text-white ease-linear transition-all duration-150 cursor-pointer"
                fillRule="currentColor"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                  clipRule="evenodd"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body relative p-4">
              <form
                onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
                className="container max-w-sm mx-auto flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-3"
              >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4 placeholder:text-sm"
                  placeholder="First Name"
                  onChange={(e) => setFirst(e.target.value)}
                  value={first_name}
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4 placeholder:text-sm"
                  placeholder="Last Name"
                  onChange={(e) => setLast(e.target.value)}
                  value={last_name}
                />
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4 placeholder:text-sm"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  value={email}
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4 placeholder:text-sm"
                  placeholder="Zipcode"
                  onChange={(e) => setZip(e.target.value)}
                  value={zipcode}
                />
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4 placeholder:text-sm"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  value={password}
                />
                {errorMessage ? (
                  <div className="flex p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-red-700 border border-red-300 rounded-lg bg-red-50 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-red-400 dark:border-red-800 items-center">
                    <img
                      src={require("../images/warning.png")}
                      width="30px"
                      style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}
                    />
                    {errorMessage}
                  </div>
                ) : null}

                <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-end p-3 border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b">
                  <button
                    // data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    className="bg-black text-white font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded inline-flex group items-center justify-center cursor-pointer"
                  >
                    <span className="absolute w-0 h-0 transition-all duration-300 ease-out bg-[#F0C797] group-hover:w-32 group-hover:h-24 opacity-10"></span>
                    Order up!
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <a
                  data-bs-toggle="modal"
                  data-bs-target="#login"
                  className="mb-6 mt-4 mx-auto text-black-500 background-transparent font-bold underline uppercase text-sm focus:outline-none ease-linear transition-all duration-150 hover:text-white cursor-pointer"
                >
                  Already have an account?
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

## **

## Here is my Nav.js**

```
mport { useState } from "react";

function Nav() {
  let [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
  // nav = false
  function handleNav() {
    setNav(!nav);
  }

  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-between items-center bg-[#FDECA9] py-3">
      <div className="mx-auto mr-25">
        <a href="/">
          <div className="flex space-x-1 tracking-[4px] text-xl font-semibold items-center">
            <span>PLATE</span>
            <img
              src={require("./images/plate.png")}
              className="h-9"
              alt="PlateMate Logo"
            />
            <span>MATE</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="hidden md:flex items-center">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="bg-[#BB5855] mx-0 rounded text-[#FDECA9] text-sm py-1 px-4 relative inline-flex group items-center justify-center cursor-pointer"
          data-bs-toggle="modal"
          data-bs-target="#signup"
        >
          <span className="absolute w-0 h-0 transition-all duration-300 ease-out bg-white rounded-full group-hover:w-32 group-hover:h-32 opacity-10"></span>
          SIGNUP
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="text-[#BB5855] mx-6 rounded text-sm outline outline-offset-4 outline-2 py-0 px-4 relative font-semibold text-center no-underline transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out cursor-pointer hover:text-[#bb58557c] "
          data-bs-toggle="modal"
          data-bs-target="#login"
        >
          LOGIN
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="block md:hidden">
        {/* Mobile Hamburger Icon */}
        <button
          onClick={handleNav}
          className="inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-3 text-sm md:hidden "
        >
          <img src={require("../src/images/hamburger.png")} width="30px" />
        </button>

        {/* Dropdown menu */}
        <div
          className={
            nav
              ? "block absolute right-0 z-10 mt-0 w-56 mr-2 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-[#BB5855] shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none"
              : "hidden"
          }
        >
          <ul className="py-1 text-sm text-gray-100 divide-y ">
            <div>
              <a
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#signup"
                className="block px-4 py-2 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out cursor-pointer hover:text-black"
              >
                SIGNUP
              </a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#login"
                className="block px-4 py-2 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out cursor-pointer hover:text-black"
              >
                LOGIN
              </a>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

I tried researching everything online but I can't find anything with Tailwind, only Bootstrap. I'm expecting the modal to not dismiss when there is an error message but dismiss completely after signed up. It does that but my issue is the grey background not disappearing. I have nothing in my CSS files that would tie to it. I've also tried commenting everything out on all of my files to see if anything was triggering it, however, it still appears. Please help!

Comment: Not sure exactly, but you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly with React just to switch a CSS class. See this question for details: [Toggle css class in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38045836/8068625)

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you aren't really using React in the way it's intended. You should me managing the state in React, and not manipulating the DOM manually.

A common pattern for removing a modal is to use a state variable to handle the visibility of the component.

```js
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
```

Then around your modal, you can render it conditionally:

```
return (<>
   {modalOpen && (<YourModelHere />)}
</>)
```

You can then hide/show your modal using the `setModalOpen()` method.

Comment: I did this and it still shows the grey background from the modal!